# Replace before and after inside string with elements from a list

Tags: python, string, list

given a string like:

```
strng = 'http://example.com/example/xyz?abc1234'
```

I want to replace everything between the last "/" and "?", i.e. replace the "xyz" part, with elements from a list, like:

```
lst = ['apple', 'banana', 'carrot']
```

so that I can do like:

```
for element in list:
    print(strng)
```

and it returns

```
http://example.com/example/apple?abc1234
http://example.com/example/banana?abc1234
http://example.com/example/carrot?abc1234
```

Comment: `for r in lst: print(strng.replace('/xyz?', '/'+r+'?'))`

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Are you trying to generate HTTP requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace `"xyz"` with a placeholder and use `str.format`:

```
strng = strng.replace('/xyz?', '/{}?')
for item in lst:
    print(strng.format(item))
```

Output:

```
http://example.com/example/apple?abc1234
http://example.com/example/banana?abc1234
http://example.com/example/carrot?abc1234
```

Answer (score 1):

```
strng = 'http://example.com/example/xyz?abc1234'
lst = ['apple', 'banana', 'carrot']

for item in lst:
    newstring = strng.replace('xyz',item)
    print (newstring)
```

Comment: I prefer the answer above over the accepted answer because this answer is complete, The code can be copied, run and the results verified without additional edits required. In the accepted answer that is not the case. To test that answer a reader must copy and place lines omitted from the original question.